# For all integers of n, $n$ is divisible by $2 \iff n^4$ is divisible by $2$

Tags: proof-writing

> Provide the proof: $\forall n \in \mathbb{Z}$, $n$ is divisible by $2
> > \iff n^4$ is divisible by $2$.

Just curious on how the proof of this statement would look like.

Comment: Welcome to math.SE!! Please use MathJax to render the math correctly. Also, could you tell us what have you tried please?

Comment: The $\Rightarrow$-side is quite easy to prove, since there are only two cases. So I would approach this by splitting the proof up to $\Rightarrow$ and $\Leftarrow$.

Comment: @manooooh As far as the proof goes, I only showed n being an even integer, while the second part, where n^4 is divisible by 2, I did not understand if the second part is acting like a condition for the first part of the statement. Just confused on the "if and only if" i guess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A number $n$ is divisible by two if and only if $n$ is even $\ldots$ equivalently, $n$ is even if and only if $n=2k$ for some $k$.

Now suppose that $n$ is even then $n=2k$ for some $k$ , so

$$n^4 = (2k)^4 = 2^4k^4 = 2\cdot2^3\cdot k^4 = 2\cdot K$$

where $K=2^3\cdot k^4$. Therefore, $n^4$ is even and hence divisible by two.  Conversely, suppose $n^4$ is divisible by $2$ but that $n$ were odd.  Then repeating the previous we get that $n=2k+1$ for some $k$ and hence that 
$$n^4 = (2k+1)^4 = 
16 k^4 + 32 k^3 + 24 k^2 + 8 k + 1 = 2K+1$$

where $K=8k^4 + 16k^3+24k^2+4k$, but then $n^4$ would be odd and hence not divisible by two (a contradiction).

Notice: This second half of the proof is essentially proof by contraposition but I sort of artificially made it a proof by contradiction (because usually people new to proofs find these easier to follow).

Comment: Quick question: so the K for when n is odd will be (8k^3+16k^3+12k^2+4k) and to show 2K+1 for the second part of the proof?

Comment: I've edited my answer to address this question.

Comment: Dike Doke....  also you should know that this question is not about "formal proofs" since it is not using formal logic.  In the future, when you ask questions you ought to include your attempt at the problem.

Answer (score 0):

One approach is to prove a more general result, of which your theorem is just a specific instance. That is, let's prove that in general:

$\forall n \in \mathbb{Z}, \forall p \in \mathbb{N}^+: \ \  n$ is divisible by $2
 \iff n^p$ is divisible by $2$

This we can prove by induction on $p$:

Base:

$p=1$.

We have to show that:

$$n \text{ is divisible by } 2
 \iff n^1 \text{ is divisible by }2$$

Well, that is trivially true, since $n^1=n$

Step:

Thye inductive hypothesis is that for some $k \in \mathbb{N}^+$, we have that:

$$n \text{ is divisible by } 2
 \iff n^k \text{ is divisible by }2$$

Now we need to show that:

$$n \text{ is divisible by } 2
 \iff n^{k+1} \text{ is divisible by }2$$

We would prove this if we can prove the following two things:

$$n \text{ is divisible by } 2
 \Rightarrow n^{k+1} \text{ is divisible by }2$$

and

$$n \text{ is not divisible by } 2
 \Rightarrow n^{k+1} \text{ is not divisible by }2$$

The first half: If $n$ is divisible by $2$, then by inductive hypothesis $n^k$ is divisible by $2$ as well, and hence $n$ and $n^k$ are both even. But the product of two even numbers is even, and hence $n^{k+1}=n \cdot n^k$ is even as well

Second half: If $n$ is not divisible by $2$, then by inductive hypothesis $n^k$ is not divisible by $2$ either. Hence, they are both odd. But the product of two odd numbers is odd, and hence $n^{k+1}=n \cdot n^k$ is odd as well, and thus not divisible by $2$